# How to pass a more variable with page/subpage in Wordprees URL?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, url, url-rewriting

> mydomain/how-we-work/our-process/

here is-

parent page->how-we-work

sub page->our-process

Now i want to pass a more value by using url.

Comment: Hi,What type of value you want to pass? You can pass many value using get method. example: mydomain/how-we-work/our-process?key="value"

Comment: **mydomain/how-we-work/our-process/a=xyz**
i want get another value in our-process(sub page) as "a"

Comment: use this mydomain/how-we-work/our-process?a=xyz&b=xyz&c=123